# Iterating over a list, modifying each element: is there a faster method?

Tags: java, list

I have an `List` of `String`s and I would like to `trim()` each element of the list.

Currently, I'm using an `ArrayList`, doing a simple loop through the elements, and adding the trimmed element to a return list, like so:

```
int listLen = listToTrim.size();

List<String> trimmedList = new ArrayList<String>( listLen );

for ( int i = 0; i < listLen; i++ ) {
    trimmedList.add( listToTrim.get( i ).trim() );
}

return trimmedList;
```

For large lists, would there be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: i don't think so,you will need to iterate using foreach or for

Comment: A more efficient way is to create a list of String which is trimmed in the first place. You could also modify the existing list unless you also need the untrimmed one as well.

Comment: If it starts being a drain on performance/productivity, you could try multithreading it. The task is simple and "standalone" enough to be easily divided among multiple workers. But that only improves performance for large enough workloads.

Comment: strings are immutable, so you do need to insert a different object.

Comment: NO! Don't use the combining solution from your EDIT! That's a really poor way of handling it. Simply use an iterator, it works well with both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` (and all other types of `List`). Avoid the indexing for loop if you don't have to use it.

Comment: OK, I see. I was under the impression that interators are slower than a for loop when used on lists that implement `RandomAccess`. I'll remove the suggestion. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Also, please don't try to answer inside the question, that'll get really confusing for future visitors of your question.

Comment: @evanjdooner Slightly slower. The amount of "slower" that is equal to how your hair is thin. It's the amount of "slower" you don't care about. Seriously, it's so minor that you can consider the two approaches equal (unless doing some _very_ specialized work). The loop overhead is nothing when compared to the `trim()` method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, you're good. That's about as efficient as it'll get. There's no magic that avoids iterating.

One point to keep in mind, 'though: If `listToTrim` is not a random-access-list (i.e. it does *not* implement [`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html)), then using an `Iterator` (or an enhanced for-loop, which uses an `Iterator` internally) instead of a traditional for-loop is usually much more efficient. The most notable `List` that doesn't implement `RandomAccess` is the `LinkedList`. Calling `l.get(300)` on a `LinkedList` with 600 elements will have to iterate through ~300 elements to get the correct one!

Modifying your code to use an enhanced for-loop would look like this:

```
public List<String> trimStrings(Listy<String> listToTrim) {
    List<String> trimmedList = new ArrayList<String>(listToTrim.size());
    for (String str : listToTrim) {
      trimmedList.add(str.trim());
    }
    return trimmedList;
}
```

If you don't need the original list any more, then re-using the original list can save memory and improve performance:

```
public void trimStringsInPlace(List<String> listToTrim) {
    ListIterator<String> it = listToTrim.listIterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
      it.set(it.next().trim());
    }
}
```

Comment: If I reuse the original list, do I need to return it? Won't it already be modified?

Comment: @evanjdooner: no, you don't need to return it. I was just assuming you wanted to keep the signature of the method the same, but it's less confusing if you don't (because then it's obvious that the passed-in list is modified), so I'll remove it.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks! I'm not too familiar with the use of iterators, so I wondered if there was some reason for returning the list. All clear now!

Comment: I provided the answer using iterator, But look at that what happens. It got downvote, but this answer got upvotes. There are people here not living on earth I think.

Answer (score 3):

Not really; you have to call `trim` on each element, and preallocating an `ArrayList` of the right size is as fast as you can get. Java 8 will allow you to make the syntax more compact, but iterating and `trim`ming is the minimum amount of work here.

Answer (score 3):

In addtion, instead of creating a new ArrayList, you can use [ArrayList#set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29). This can  reduce the memory footprint considerably for larger lists.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < listLen; i++ ) {
    listToTrim.set(i,listToTrim.get( i ).trim());
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to keep the original list of untrimmed strings, and are happy to mutate the list in-place (which raises a risk of bugs if the list is shared with other bits of code), then this is the way to go.

Comment: Note also that you can use a [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) to modify the list in an iterator style rather than using get/set.

Comment: Calling `get(i)` *and* `set(i)` can really ruin your runtime when working with any non-random-access list (such as `LinkedList`)! Try to benchmark that with a few thousand strings in a `LinkedList` and compare it with the same code on an `ArrayList`. The difference should be quite obvious.

Comment: @JoachimSauer If its non- RandomAccess, agreed. And that is why I stuck with `ArrayList` in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Joachim already answered the question. But one suggestion-

**listToTrim** - when you add items to listToTrim, trim first before you add. That way, you don't have to iterate and modify or create another list just to do so. It doesn't sound logical.

**Edit** based from comment:

```
String fruits = "Apple, Banana   , Mango, Passion Fruit, Grapes  ";

List<String> fruitList = Arrays.asList((fruits.trim()).split("\\s*,\\s*")); // Trim first and then regex matches spaces before and after comma

for(String fruit : fruitList){
    System.out.println("Fruit: " + fruit + "\tLength: " + fruit.length());
}
```

**Output:**

```
Fruit: Apple           Length: 5
Fruit: Banana          Length: 6
Fruit: Mango           Length: 5
Fruit: Passion Fruit   Length: 13
Fruit: Grapes          Length: 6
```

Comment: `listToTrim` is created from an array produced by splitting a comma-separated String. I'm not sure how I could pre-trim it, without just performing a similar action on the array returned by `split()`.

Comment: @evanjdooner: you can use `split("\\s*,\\s*")`. Then you only need to `trim()` the first and the last value.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You beat me to that.

Comment: This makes the trimming method redundant. Marked as best answer.

Comment: @evanjdooner: so what did you learn from this? If you ask "How do I do Y?" it's good to mention **why** you want to do Y, because sometimes you can modify how you do an earlier X to make Y unnecessary (that's called an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). In the future, please try to include more context to allow those kinds of answers.

Comment: @evanjdooner You should have chosen Joachim Sauer's answer as accepted as his solution is well defined for the problem you specified in your question. Mine was just a suggestion.

Comment: @JoachimSauer - I asked about the solution to my problem because I was interested in better understanding the characteristics of different list types and algorithms. I wasn't aware of what an XY Problem is. I'll keep that in mind in the future. SajalDutta - I agree that Joachim Sauer's answer was a better solution to the question I asked. Choice switched.

Answer (score 3):

Joachim got it right. The people saying you should trim your strings before putting them in the first list got it right, too.

Anyway, if the latter is not an option for you, there might be an alternative approach: Are you sure you will use all the trimmed strings? Or will you use only a few of them, say, possibly only the first five of them? Then it might be an overkill to trim them all.

You can design a special `List` implementation that will store the original list, but will give out the elements trimmed. Here's what I mean by it:

```
public class ImmutableStringTrimmingList extends AbstractList<String> {

    private final List<String> stringList;

    public ImmutableStringTrimmingList(List<String> stringList) {
        this.stringList = stringList;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(int index) {
        return stringList.get(index).trim();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return stringList.size();
    }

}
```

The `ImmutableStringTrimmingList` stores the original list (so any changes to that list will propagate here, too) and hands out the `String` objects lazily trimmed. This can be helpful if you don't want to do any needless work as it will only trim the Strings that are requested by `get()`. It can also be adapted to cache the trimmed object so it won't have to retrim it every time. But that's a practice for you if you'll find this class helpful.

---

Or, if you're a Guava user, you can use [`Lists.transform()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) which basically does the same thing, also lazily.

```
List<String> trimmedList = Lists.transform(list, new Function<String, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(String input) {
        return input.trim();
    }
});
```

Comment: All the strings will be used, yes. That's unfortunate, because I really like this answer.

Comment: @evanjdooner Well, if you'll access all the strings once, it will do the same work as all the other solutions (trim the strings). If you'll access them multiple times, you might need to add some caching (e.g. replacing the non-trimmed strings with the trimmed ones) etc. and that's where this begins to be a waste :).

Comment: Nice alternative! If you happen to do this occasionally, then the Guava [`Lists.transform()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform(java.util.List, com.google.common.base.Function)) might interest you, because it pretty much does exactly this.